# Objective-C Question about adding a method

Tags: objective-c

Im a newbie to Objective -C and having some issues with an assignment.
The question is:
Add a Method declaration called buttonClick that takes in a variable of type id called sender, and "returns" an IBAction event

I have no idea how to do this
This is what I have so Far but getting errors

```
// method declaration called ButtonClick
@property (nonatomic,assign)  id  ButtonClick;
- (IBAction)return:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: The code you wrote does not make sense at all. I suggest you read an Objective-C tutorial first: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/ and/or http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html

Answer (score 2):

Methods are declared in an `@interface` and defined in an `@implementation`. An interface declaration is usually put in a `.h` file and looks something like this:

```
// Here we are deriving from NSObject, but it is not uncommon to subclass
// from other classes like NSView.

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    int clickCount;
}

- (IBAction) buttonClick:(id) sender;
- (IBAction) resetCounter:(id) sender;

@end
```

The implementation of the method typically goes in a `.m` file, and can look something like this:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (IBAction) buttonClick:(id) sender
{
    clickCount++;
    NSLog(@"Button has been clicked %d time(s)", clickCount);
}

- (IBAction) resetCounter:(id) sender
{
    clickCount = 0;
}

@end
```

Use Interface Builder to connect one button to the `buttonClick:` method, and another button to the `resetCounter:` method.

Comment: Answered the question, helpful comments and no snark. You're winning at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Kevin: if this is the answer you were looking for, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make a button press method? Google is your friend. But this may help:

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {

    [self insertOtherMethodToDoHere];

}
```

Not sure what you mean by returns an IBAction, but hope that helped.

Comment: Don't name your methods using an initial uppercase letter. The convention for method naming is [lowerCamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Variations_and_synonyms).

Comment: I was using his already intended method name. See the question. But you are correct, that's the better way to do it.